# Error building OpenCV for iPhone

Tags: iphone, build, opencv, makefile

I'm trying to build OpenCV for iPhone. When I launch the make command I get this error message

```
 s.framework/Headers/AXUIElement.h:65: error: ‘CGCharCode’ has not been declared
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/AXUIElement.h:65: error: ‘CGKeyCode’ has not been declared
make[3]: *** [src/highgui/CMakeFiles/highgui.dir/loadsave.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/highgui/CMakeFiles/highgui.dir/all] Error 2
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

thanks a lot

Elos

Comment: This problem is better posed to the OpenCV team than to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: you can't build highgui for ARM (iPhone). Only link to the binaries you really need from the OpenCV project, e.g. libcvxyz.